# Why are my desktop entries greyed out / red x in bottom corner despite working perfectly fine?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, .desktop

It seems to be very weird, the entries are copies of my `.local/share/applications` entries (where they are also shown correctly with no issues) and until yesterday, they looked fine on my desktop as well. It furthermore cannot be a permissions problem, since rwx is set.
In fact, this is only a visual problem, the scripts work fine and my apps are launching right away.
Has anybody experienced the same situation or has an idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

[What the well-functioning applications look like on my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubmFH.png)

Comment: Ownership is OK?

Comment: Yes, I just set it with `sudo chown -R $USER ~/Desktop`, problem still occurs.

Comment: Also after you log out then back in?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.
What is furthermore strange is, on each login, I have to `allow launching` anew.